# Why this code is repeating files in listbox?

Tags: c#, ftp, webrequest, ftp-client

I want to list all files from my ftp folder, I am using this code. But it gives me twice the name of files. What is wrong with it?

```
private void ListFilesOnServer()
        {
            try
            {
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("IncomingFtpPath"));
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(line) == ".xml")
                    {
                        WaitingListBox.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(line));
                    }
                }

                reader.Close();
                response.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use a debugger to see what is contain in "response"
- Make sure that your function is called only once.
- Also, are your sure that the "duplicates" are not files with the same name but different absolute paths ?

Few remarks on your code:

- Prefer using directives when manipulating streams, instead of manually closing them : here your code might throw exceptions without releasing the resources.
- Avoid swallowing exceptions (even if you display them)

  ```
  private void ListFilesOnServer()

  {
          try
          {
       FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("IncomingFtpPath"));

              request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");

              request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
              FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

              using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
              {
                 string line = null;
                 while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                 {
                  if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(line) == ".xml")
                  {
                    WaitingListBox.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(line));
                  }
                 }
              }
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
              // throw e
          }
  ```